# Google App Engine Datastore Reindex Existing Entities

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I added a new index to my GAE app, but I need to index old entities. Is there any way besides getting and reinserting to create index entries for existing entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to re-save all old entities. The Datastore only updates indexes when an entity is saved.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides tools - [gcd](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/) for Java and [appcfg.py](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp?#Python_Updating_indexes) for Python/Go - that can [add and remove indexes on your production datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig#Datastore_Updating_indexes).